# php preg_match value or semicolon before newline

Tags: php, regex, email, preg-match-all

I'm trying to parse a mailheader, but I can't seem to find how to get the part from the header which have a newline after a semicolon.

Example:

```
Content-Type: multipart/related;
    type="multipart/alternative";
    boundary="----_=_NextPart_002_01CF36FC.6259F03C"
```

I'm parsing this with the following regex in preg_match_all:

```
/(?P<keyname>.*):(\s*)?(?<value>(?:(?!;).)+)((\s*)?;([\s\\r\\n\\t]*)?(?<sub_value>.*)))?/i
```

But this isn't giving me the boundary line inside the sub_value.
I tried also with

```
(?<sub_value>(.+|;[\s\\r\\n\\t]*))
```

instead of

```
(?<sub_value>.*)
```

but it doesn't change anything.

```
.+|;[\s\\r\\n\\t]*<br>
```

as in all characters, or a semicolon with a newline/tab after it

Thanks in advance!

Edit:
When I'm using

```
(?<sub_value>([\w_.=\"\/\-;\s\\r\\n\\t]*))
```

I'm getting the boundary part too but it's getting more than it should be, and are all the characters included that can be present in a mailboundary?
Also, it catches the newline without having  a semicolon.

Comment: How do you want the matches array to look like? In other words, what exactly do you wish to be captured?

Comment: Actually, the Content-Type will get into 'keyname', and the value after the : will get into 'value'. All other arguments, which are after a semicolon into sub_value which will be parsed later in the code. But if there is another keyword, or how you can call it, it needs to get into another subarray (it will have another key in the result array).
A good matcharray will look like this:
[keyname] => Array [0] => Content-Type
[value] => Array [0] => multipart/related
[sub_value] => Array [0] => type="multipart/alternative";
 boundary="----_=_NextPart_002_01CF36FC.6259F03C"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
$headers = <<<EOT
Host: www.example.com
Content-Length: 9000
Content-Type: multipart/related;
    type="multipart/alternative";
    boundary="----_=_NextPart_002_01CF36FC.6259F03C"
X-Http: ok
EOT;

preg_match_all("/(?P<keyname>[a-zA-Z0-9-]+):(?P<value>.*?)[\n\r;]+(?P<sub_value>[\s\S]*?)(?=$|[a-zA-Z0-9-]+:)/", $headers, $match);
```

You can get the explanation of regex from [this link](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl). Just remove the `(?:P<...>)` from the regex when you try to get the explanation using [the link](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The regex you gave almost worked, though I needed to edit it a bit, because I couldn't get 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable' where 'X-Http: ok' is in your example:
/(?P<keyname>[a-zA-Z0-9-]+):(?P<value>(?:(?!;).)+)([\s\n\r;]+)?(?P<sub_value>[\s\S]*?)(?=$|[a-zA-Z0-9-]+:)/

Answer (score 0):

According to <strike>[RFC1341](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html)</strike> [RFC1521](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1521.html) I believe that this regex contains the possible boundary characters:

```
$regex = "/"
       . "(?P<keyname>.*)"
       . ":(\s*)?"
       . "(?<value>(?:(?!;).)+)"
       . "("
       . "(\s*)?;"
       . "([\s\\r\\n\\t]*)?"
       . "(?<sub_value>(['()+_,\-.:;?=\"\/\w\s\\r\\n\\t]*))"
       . ")?"
       . "/i";
```

**EDIT** updated RFC link and regex